# Database Design (Quotation & Invoicing)

Tags: database-design

I have a database question.
I have a database structured something like this:
Quotation, Quotation_line_item

When I convert the quotation to an invoice, is where im stuck wondering:
Should i make tables as such
Invoice, Invoice_line_item

Or should the Invoice just refer to the quotation line items?

Anyone with some experience can maybe help me with some advice on what would be best?

I know that if you change the Quotation the Invoice will change too - but when generating an invoice we are going to be locking the quotation for editing.

What would you recommend?

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an entity goes through processing which results in differing states, those states should be maintained in a separate table. The line items don't seem to be a problem. Have you designed the quotation line items such that the latest ones (assuming you keep previous versions as history) become invoice line items when the quotation becomes an invoice? That is easily done since it doesn't appear there is any actual difference between the two -- only context distinguishes them.

So you would have the QuoteInvoice table, the state table with an FK to the first table and the line items table also with an FK to the first table, a line number and a date (if you keep versions) for when the version became effective.

Comment: sorry im only seeing this now. yes i did sort of as you describe. i have the quote table and when its invoiced there is an entry in invoice table referencing the quote id (the invoice table is literally like id,quote_id,dateadded)